# Horizontal scrollable Textview which is in listview in Android?

Tags: android, textview, scrollable

I have a Listview in which there are 3-4 textviews. I am using the BaseAdapter way where I am inflating xml. All the textviews are single line. I want to make the textview horizontally scrollable. I have tried to put the textview inside HorizontalScrollview. Well, that did scrolled the textview but then I was not able to get the click event of listview.

Is there any other way I can make the textview scrollable horizontally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by adding this line to first RelativeLayout in the xml file android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants". In this way no child will have focus and so the horizontal scrollbar also works and listview item clicks also works. It worked for me. Anyways, thanks everyone.

Comment: ya u r right I was also facing same problem and solved it by your answer....android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no easy way to do this.

The problem is that scroll view consume all touch events. To solve this one should make sure that horizontal scroll view consume only "horizontal" move events.

First you should implement you own scroll view. Then override onTouchEvent() of that view so it only consume "more horizontal than vertical" gestures and left "vertical" gestures for list view.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [ellipsize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize) property of the TextView class. If you set it to `marquee` the text should automatically scroll when it is focused.

Comment: I've done this in the past and it works ok.  However, it doesn't give the user control over the text like the OP wants.

Comment: Ok. I think it's really hard to get a good user experience with a ScrollView within a ListView. But I'm interested in your solution when you solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't anybody use `TextView.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance())` with `android:scrollHorisontally="true"`?